# Python 3.4.3.: sum of all the lengths of strings in binary string tree

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, string-length

So I need to define a recursive function called `total_len()`, that takes a Binary String Tree and returns the sum of the lengths of all the leaves. So `total_len( ( ("one", ("two","three")) , ("four","five") ) )` should return 19, `total_len( ("left","right") )` should return 9, and `total_len("One-leaf")` should return 8. I don't really know where to start, and I know that what I have is completely wrong, but what I have so far is this:

```
def total_len(BST):
    """Takes a binary string tree and returns the sum of all the lengths of
    of all the leaves.

    BST->int"""
    if isinstance(BST,tuple):
        return total_len(len(BST[0][0])+total_len(len(BST[1][0])))
    else:
        return BST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could something like this:

```
def total_len(bst):
    if isinstance(bst, tuple):
        if bst == ():
            return 0
        else:
            return total_len(bst[0]) + total_len(bst[1:])
    else:
        return len(bst)
```